# Need help to implement thread pool for REST web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, threadpool

I have gone through many threads, but did not get specific solution over how to implement thread pool on any web service call, where I have a REST service created.

Just giving a high level idea -

1) Calling web service through servlet
2) Every request coming to servlet hitting the web service should be put in queue if the prior request has not been processed completely with the return of response
3) Assuming application server is up and running on 8080 port, it is difficult for me to implement thread pool giving error -
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
4) I am not sure about how to handle it end to end for putting requests in queue for web service call in servlet

Here is the code description -

1) A servlet class with doPost() calling my REST service

```
 HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
   String requrl = "http://myappserver:8080/TestApp/test/testExecute.service";

   String jsonvalue = "{\"param1\":\"value1"," +
                        "\"param2\":\"value2\"}";

   LOG.info("json value: " + jsonvalue);

   HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(requrl);

   String message = jsonvalue;

   StringEntity input = new StringEntity(message);

   input.setContentType("application/json");

   postRequest.setEntity(input);

   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

2) Web service -

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonPropertyOrder;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonWriteNullProperties;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@JsonWriteNullProperties(false)

@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "param1",
        "param2"
    })

public class TestExecuteRequest implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
        protected String param1;
        @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
        protected String param2;

        /**
         * @return the param1
         */
        public String getParam1() {
            return param1;
        }
        /**
         * @param param1 the param1 to set
         */
        public void setParam1(String param1) {
            this.param1 = param1;
        }
        /**
         * @return the param2
         */
        public String getParam2() {
            return param2;
        }
        /**
         * @param param2 the param2 to set
         */
        public void setParam2(String param2) {
            this.param2 = param2;
        }
     }

 Class having web service definition -

 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

 import javax.ws.rs.POST;

 import javax.ws.rs.Path;

 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

 import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.Formatted;

 @Path("test")

 public interface TestFrame {

    @POST

    @Consumes("application/json")

    @Formatted

    @Produces("application/json")

    @Path("/testExecute.service")

    Response executeTestSuite(TestExecuteRequest testExeRequest);

}

Web service performing some operations in TestService class

public class TestService implements TestFrame {

    // Logic to perform all operations after web service has been called

}
```

Can anyone help me, where to write thread pool in any of the above classes so that the requests can be processed one after the other when calling this above mentioned web service in servlet?

Would appreciate your help.

Thank you,
MN

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve first the "port already use" error that is not related to the thread.

> it is difficult for me to implement thread pool giving error - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

It means that your port is already use by another process. You can use the netstat command to see which process is using your port. If you are on a Linux machine try this

```
netstat -annp | grep 8080
```

Note that the -p flag will give you the process id that is using the 8080 port.

Comment: Sorry to mention more details, I tried the ThreadPool logic as available on internet for a small task, which did not solve my issue and gave me the BindException. That is the reason I provided all code details, please explain me from scratch how can I handle the queues or threadpool required to handle multiple requests for web service call.

Comment: Could you add the  following in your implementation of executeTestSuite ? Print the current thread name to check if your container is not already creating multiple threads for you.